# How can I get a thicker underline?

Tags: html, css

I have some bold text and would like to underline to appear bold as well.

[image]

**HTML**

`<p>Home Page</p>`

**CSS**

```
p {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/164gg76m/3/)**

---

I tried several thing but they didn't work well.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `border-bottom`?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela the solution to that answer doesn't work for me, it's not the desired reuslt

Comment: There is a large number of duplicates of this question, mostly without the correct answer, which is “You cannot” and different workarounds suggested. If you are referring to problems with the workarounds, you need to specify exactly what you tried and how it fails. And you should probably do this in a new question, after checking that an essentially similar question has not been asked and answered.

Comment: @Vader You should accept one of the answers, especially since one of them caters for more than your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `border-bottom` with some padding:

```
display:inline-block;
border-bottom:solid 2px red;
padding-bottom:2px;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow4mhhg5/2/)

Edit:

To achieve the effect you want, you can wrap the text with a `<span>`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mm1ofpje/1/)

Comment: That doesn't work in my case because the border is shown under the box.  http://i.imgur.com/cELSYTe.png

Comment: In that case you'll need to change the elements wrapping the text. Could you paste the full code?

Comment: @Vader updated my answer with an example.

Comment: That still doesn't work, here is my actual code.   http://jsfiddle.net/164gg76m/4/

Comment: @Vader Here you go, I applied it to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/e4yLL7La/

Comment: the underline should be inside of the box, only covering the length of the text. http://i.imgur.com/g5OVQjo.png

Comment: Oh right, you just need to remove the padding from the `li` and apply it to the span instead: http://jsfiddle.net/e4yLL7La/1/

Comment: That's the same link as before, I can't tell the difference

Comment: Try again, I updated it seconds after posting the comment.

Comment: Looks even weirder :D http://i.imgur.com/CEPYi4l.png

Comment: It's because you have a `border-bottom` on hover declaration for your list items. If you remove that, it will work as you expect. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/3utjyy5g/1/show/ 

You can now tweak the code to only show the new border on hover :)

Comment: That looks better but All I want is the line to be 2px instead of 1px, This is once again too long and too low.

Comment: I've answered the original question and tweaked it as you desired, according to your screenshots. If you want the border width to be a certain width, change it.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to use pseudo-element `:after` to mimic border. Benefit in this case is that it's easy to control "border" offset with `margin-top`. For example:

```css
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
p:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<p>Home Page</p>
```